# Specifying the exact java version in maven and the corresponding version in dokerfile

Tags: java, docker, maven, dockerfile, pom.xml

I'm working on a Java project using Maven where the pom.xml file sets the Java version as **11**, without specifying an exact version (e.g., 11.0.3). In the corresponding Dockerfile, I'm using the OpenJDK image specified as **openjdk:11.0.12-jdk**

I'd like to understand the best practices or recommendations regarding aligning the Java version between the Maven project configuration and the Dockerfile. Should the version specified in the pom.xml be more precise, matching the specific version used in the Dockerfile? Or is it acceptable to have a broader declaration in the pom.xml without specifying an exact version while using a specific version in the Dockerfile?

Comment: Usually you define only as you already mentioned like `11` via `<maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>`. The version in docker file might be change over the time as well which is tracked by your version control system... and usually there should no issue related to the patch version ... apart from that the 11.0.12 seemed to be a bit out of date..11.0.20 or even 11.0.21... I would always use the latest patch version in the container.

Comment: @khmarbaise i mentioned java version simply like that :                          
   <properties>
  <java.version>11</java.version>
 </properties>                                                                                                                              and not with     <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>

Comment: First you don't have mentioned that. Apart from that you should use `<maven.compiler.release>..</maven.compiler.release>`instead in particular with JDK9+ .  The `java.version` is usually related to spring boot project... but you don't mentioned that project is something like a spring boot project if so use the `java.version` ...